# GridView header text not showing when binded dynamically for first time

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a GridView, which is populated using a linq query on button click.

I have to populate the header text dynamically, fetching from the database. The first time I click the button, the header text is not binding. But, if I click on the button a second time, the header texts are bound.

Markup:

```
   <asp:GridView ID="grdresult" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" 
            OnRowDataBound="grdresult_RowDataBound">                   
            <Columns>                        
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderStyle-Width="10%">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                       <asp:Label ID="lblCol1" runat="server" Text=' <%#Eval("Col1") %>'></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderStyle-Width="10%">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="lblCol2" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Col2") %>'></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderStyle-Width="10%">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Col3") %>'></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderStyle-Width="10%">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                       <asp:Label ID="lblCol4" runat="server" Text=' <%#Eval("Col4") %>'></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderStyle-Width="10%">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="lblCol5" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Col5") %>'></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderStyle-Width="10%">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                       <asp:Label ID="lblCol6" runat="server" Text=' <%#Eval("Col6") %>'></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderStyle-Width="10%">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                       <asp:Label ID="lblCol7" runat="server" Text=' <%#Eval("Col7") %>'></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderStyle-Width="10%">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                       <asp:Label ID="lblCol8" runat="server" Text=' <%#Eval("Col8") %>'></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
            </Columns>
            <EmptyDataTemplate>
            No Records Found
           </EmptyDataTemplate>
        </asp:GridView>
```

Codebehind:

```
protected void btnreport_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{       
    BindGrid();     
}

protected void BindGrid()
{  
    var results = "LINQ select query from database";
                       }).Distinct().ToList();

    for (int i = 0; i < grdresult.Columns.Count; i++)
    {
        grdresult.Columns[i].Visible = true;
    }

    grdresult.DataSource = results;
    grdresult.DataBind();       

}

protected void grdresult_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{

    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Header)
    {
        var getColumnHeader = "LINQ query to get header text";
        if (getColumnHeader != null)
        {
            grdresult.Columns[5].HeaderText = getColumnHeader.HCol3;
            grdresult.Columns[6].HeaderText = getColumnHeader.HCol4;
            grdresult.Columns[7].HeaderText = getColumnHeader.HCol5;
            grdresult.Columns[8].HeaderText = getColumnHeader.HCol6;
            grdresult.Columns[9].HeaderText = getColumnHeader.HCol7;
            grdresult.Columns[10].HeaderText = getColumnHeader.HCol8;
            grdresult.Columns[11].HeaderText = getColumnHeader.HCol9;
            grdresult.Columns[12].HeaderText = getColumnHeader.HCol10;                    
        }
    }

    //based on some condition i have set visibility of gridview columns
    int TotalColumnCount = (int)ViewState["colcount"];
    for (int i = grdresult.Columns.Count - 1; i > TotalColumnCount + 4; i--)
    {
        grdresult.Columns[i].Visible = false;
    }        
}
```

Comment: What means "for the first time", are you databinding the grid at all on `!IsPostBack`? Do you need to click on the button twice?

Comment: Only on button click I'm binding the gridview. The data gets binded to gridview properly on first button click except the header text. On click of button again header text appears

Comment: Try putting the header row related code in a handler for RowCreated event instead.

Comment: what happen if you bind your gridview on page_Load like this protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {        
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
           Binfgrid();
        }
    }

Comment: Hummm, I think you are using the wrong event for that. The RowDataBound event, triggers, everytime the datagrid will create a row with data. I think the event you need is OnDataBound, that's triggered after the grid binded everything.

Comment: I tried in RowCreated and OnDataBound event but no change in the output

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the below line for binding header text
grdresult.Columns[5].HeaderText = getColumnHeader.HCol3;

i used below line which solved the issue.

e.Row.Cells[5].Text = getColumnHeader.HCol3;

Answer (score 0):

This error can also occur if you are dumping an integer value into varchar() but the size of varchar is not enough. For example I was getting this error as I was cast sum() to varchar(10), and hence the error.

**I changed varchar(10) to varchar(20) and the error got resolved.**

Answer (score -1):

In Gridview control set `ClientIDMode = "Static"`